# Angular reactive Form error: Must supply a value for form control with name:

Tags: angular, forms, typescript

I premise I am very novice with angular. I am trying to implement an angular reactive form, but I am encountering this error: "Must supply a value for form control with name: Destination.

This is the relevant parts of my component and my html:

```
import { Component, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from "@angular/http";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'home',
    templateUrl: './home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {

    locations: Location[];
    flightChoice: FlightChoice;
    form: FormGroup;


    constructor(http: Http, @Inject('BASE_URL') private baseUrl: string,
        private fb: FormBuilder) {

        this.createForm();

        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/FlightChoice/dest_locations').subscribe(result => {
            this.locations = result.json() as Location[];
            console.log(this.locations);

        }, error => console.error(error));

        http.get(baseUrl + 'api/FlightChoice/choice').subscribe(result => {
            this.flightChoice = result.json() as FlightChoice;
            this.updateForm();
        }, error => console.error(error));

    }

    createForm() {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            Destination: [0],
            NrPasg: [1],
            TwoWays: [false],
            DepartureDate: ['', Validators.required],
            ReturnDate: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }

    updateForm() {

        this.form.setValue({
            Destination: this.flightChoice.DestinationId,
            NrPasg: this.flightChoice.NrPasg,
            TwoWays: this.flightChoice.TwoWays,
            DepartureDate: this.flightChoice.DepartureDate,
            ReturnDate: this.flightChoice.ReturnDate
        });

    }
```

html:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <div>
            <label for="destination">Destination:</label>
            <br />
            <select id="destination" formControlName="Destination">
                <option *ngFor="let location of locations" value="{{ location.id }}">
                    {{ location.name }}
                </option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <label for="nrPasg">Number of Passengers:</label>
            <br />
            <input formControlName="NrPasg" type="number" id="nrPasg" value="1" />
            <label for="twoWays"></label>
            <br />
            <select id="twoWays" formControlName="TwoWays">
                <option value="false">one way</option>
                <option value="true">two ways</option>
            </select>
            <br />
            <label for="departureDate">Departure Date:</label>
            <br />
            <input formControlName="DepartureDate" type="date" id="departureDate" />
            <br />
            <label for="returnDate">Return Date:</label>
            <br />
            <input formControlName="ReturnDate" type="date" id="returnDate" />

        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Search Flights</button>

        </div>
    </form>
```

I know I am probably writing something wrong in the CreateForm method but I am not sure how to assign the values

Comment: for SEO, `Error: NG01002` brought me here

Answer (score 161):

This error can appear if you're using `setValue` on a `formGroup` but not passing in a value for every control within that group. For example:

```
let group = new FormGroup({
  foo: new FormControl(''), 
  bar: new FormControl('')
});
group.setValue({foo: 'only foo'}); //breaks
group.setValue({foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar'}); //works
```

If you truly want to only update *some* of the controls on the group, you can use `patchValue` instead:

```
group.patchValue({foo: 'only foo, no problem!'});
```

Docs for `setValue` and `patchValue` [here](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#updating-parts-of-the-data-model)

Comment: Argg this saved me, thanks. Was going crazy over this. I could not find any issues in my code. Turned out I had initial seeding data for development, and that data missed a property. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately 'undefined' isn't allowed, you need to set each property to 'null'.

You can convert properties before calling `setValue` with something like this:

```
   // set all 'missing' OR 'undefined' properties to null
   const newValue: any = {...value};

   for (const field in this.controls) { 

       if (newValue[field] === undefined) {
           newValue[field] = null;
       }
   }

   super.setValue(newValue, options);
```

Watch out because `JSON.stringify()` will remove `undefined`, and so if you use that to send a value *back* to your server you need to make sure it can handle missing properties there.

---

Alternative way, and this is more of a Javascript tip than anything:

You can use [`??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) when setting properties to ensure they're null. This may help in some cases.

eg.

```
form.setValue({

   firstName: firstName ?? null,    // null if firstName === undefined
   lastName: lastName ?? null

})
```

This is favorable to using `||` since a numeric form value (and a form value can be any type) of `0` would get wiped out by this. (Since `0 || null` => `null` and not `0`).

Comment: When I get a chance I want to propose a new option `allowUndefined`, which would allow all `undefined` properties to be treated as if they were `null`. And also `allowMissing` which would allow missing properties, and set missing properties to null.

Answer (score 12):

Probably the error appears because `this.flightChoice.DestinationId === undefined` and you try to set `undefined` to the `Destination` field on the form.

Check if api is correctly downloading data to `this.flightChoice`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem For example, the model that I was building to the form, some of the form items were not in that model and that's why I faced this problem.

> For example, my form is like this

```
this.form = new FormGroup({
   name: new FormControl(),
   family : new FormControl(),
   age: new FormControl(),
   email : new FormControl()
})
```

> The model I was building was like this

```
 const model = {
   name : 'davod',
   family : 'beheshti',
   age : "23"
 }

 this.form.setValue({...model})
```

And this error happened to me about **email**

By adding email to the model, my problem was completely solved