# Error: Must supply a value for form control with name: <name>

Tags: angular, typescript

I am having a nested operation in order to first remove an offer and then save it again as a repeating one.

The problem is, that after saving the repeating offer, I want to `patchValue()` the item in `offerList[index]`. This is where I am getting the error:

> Error: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'id'.

Debugging however revealed that everything should be fine. The object `saved` in the final subscription has valid fields set. `id` is present and not null:

```
this._offerService.remove(this.placeId, offer)
  .pipe(
    flatMap((removed: OfferModel) => {
      // Re-use the removed offer to save a repeating one
      removed.id = null;
      removed.repeatWeekly = true;
      return this._offerService.save(this.placeId, removed)
        .pipe(finalize(() => this.updateOffersFormArray()));
    }),
  )
  .subscribe(
    (saved) => {
      console.log(saved);
      // offerList is either this.offers or this.repeatingOffers
      offerList[index].patchValue(saved);
    });
```

The console will log:

```
{id: 55, offerDate: "2019-03-04", …}
```

This is what happens in `updateOffersFormArray()`:

```
// this.offersFormArray is a FormArray
updateOffersFormArray() {
  const tmp = this.repeatingOffers.concat(this.offers);
  console.log(tmp);
  this.offersFormArray.setValue(tmp); // <-- Throws error
}
```

The console ouput shows me an array of `FormGroup` elements, as expected, and each `value` of those `FormGroup` elements has an offer which has all the values set - especially `id` - which is according to the error message not set.

I'm scratching my head over this for quite some time now and I just don't see it.

I know the code looks a bit weird. After `updateOffersFormArray()` gets executed, the status change event of `this.offersFormArray` will update `this.offers` and `this.repeatingOffers` which I need for displaying purposes. Just to complete the picture, here is the code which does that:

```
this.offersFormArray.statusChanges.subscribe((e) => {
  const offers: Array<AbstractControl> = [];
  const repeatingOffers: Array<AbstractControl> = [];

  for (const k of Object.keys(this.offersFormArray.controls)) {
    const offerForm = this.offersFormArray.controls[k];
    const offer = <OfferModel> offerForm.value;

    if (offer.repeatWeekly) {
      repeatingOffers.push(offerForm);
    } else {
      offers.push(offerForm);
    }
  }

  this.offers = offers;
  this.repeatingOffers = repeatingOffers;
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular reactive Form error: Must supply a value for form control with name:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047540/angular-reactive-form-error-must-supply-a-value-for-form-control-with-name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was mistaken about `setValue()` of the `FormArray`. It does not accept a list of `AbstractControl` but instead it requires the values which match the structure of the control.

All I had to do was change

```
this.offersFormArray.setValue(tmp);
```

to

```
this.offersFormArray.setValue(tmp.map(control => control.value));
```

Comment: this way will show error at Angular 11 `Cannot find form control at index 1`