# Reactive form Must supply a value for form control with name

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am getting the error:

> Must supply a value for form control with name 'alternate'

Not sure why is the case in my angular reactive form. If you see in the code below, I have initialised alternate which is nested `formGroup`.
Could you let me know what could be the reason as the examples that I am seeing is similar to the one that I have done. Its very strange as there are few value changes methods on the form which I have commented to avoid triggering any updates. The moment I add a new control , it flags with this error. So the error is not just limited to alternate. This were also happens when I add a form control to the parent form group

**Component:**

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    yesNoMultilingual: [{ value: false, disabled: this.readonly }],
    hasDifferentPrincipalAddress: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }, Validators.required],
    differentPrincipalAddress: [
      { value: null, disabled: this.readonly },
      [
        conditionalValidator(() => this.form.hasDifferentPrincipalAddress.value, requiredAddress)
      ]
    ],
    hasDifferentMailingAddress: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }, Validators.required],
    differentMailingAddress: [
      { value: null, disabled: this.readonly },
      [
        conditionalValidator(() => this.form.hasDifferentMailingAddress.value, requiredAddress)
      ]
    ],
    hasOtherBusinessAddresses: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }, Validators.required],
    otherAddresses: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }, requiredIfValidator(() => this.form.hasOtherBusinessAddresses.value)],
    alternate: this.formBuilder.group({
      differentPrincipalAddress: [{ value: null, disabled: this.readonly }]
    }),
  });
}
```

**Markup:**

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" novalidate>
  <div class="flex-group">
    <div class="flex-2">
      <fieldset class="boxed">
        <legend translate for="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress">
          details.main-address
        </legend>
        <app-yes-no
          [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }"
          name="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress"
          formControlName="hasDifferentPrincipalAddress"
        ></app-yes-no>
        <aa-alert
          alertClass="error"
          alertText="{{ 'common.required' | translate }}"
          *ngIf="(form.hasDifferentPrincipalAddress.touched || submitted) && form.hasDifferentPrincipalAddress.errors?.required"
        ></aa-alert>
      </fieldset>

      <div
        class="field boxed"
        *ngIf="this.alternateLanguageSelected && form.hasDifferentPrincipalAddress.value">
        <app-yes-no-multilingual
          name="yesNoMultilingual"
          formControlName="yesNoMultilingual"
          id="yesNoMultilingual"
          [description]="'common.yesno-multilingual-text'"
        ></app-yes-no-multilingual>
      </div>

      <div
        class="field dependant"
        *ngIf="form.hasDifferentPrincipalAddress.value">
        <div class="field">
          <app-address
            formControlName="differentPrincipalAddress"
            [submitted]="submitted"
          ></app-address>
        </div>
      </div>

      <fieldset>
        <legend translate for="hasDifferentMailingAddress">
          details.mailing-address
        </legend>
        <app-yes-no
          [ngClass]="{ submitted: submitted }"
          name="hasDifferentMailingAddress"
          formControlName="hasDifferentMailingAddress"
        ></app-yes-no>
        <aa-alert
          alertClass="error"
          alertText="{{ 'common.required' | translate }}"
          *ngIf="(form.hasDifferentMailingAddress.touched || submitted) &&
            form.hasDifferentMailingAddress.errors?.required"
        ></aa-alert>
      </fieldset>

      <div
        class="field dependant"
        *ngIf="form.hasDifferentMailingAddress.value">
        <div class="field">
          <app-address
            formControlName="differentMailingAddress"
            [disabled]="readonly"
            [submitted]="submitted"
          ></app-address>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flex-2">
      <div class="field dependant" *ngIf="form.yesNoMultilingual.value">
        <div class="field" formGroupName="alternate">
          <app-address
            formControlName="differentPrincipalAddress"
            [submitted]="submitted"
            [showAlternateLanguageFields]="form.yesNoMultilingual.value"
          ></app-address>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular reactive Form error: Must supply a value for form control with name:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047540/angular-reactive-form-error-must-supply-a-value-for-form-control-with-name)

Comment: This happens when you call `setValue(values)` and `values` does not have properties for all of your form controls.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I have checked my component and I am not calling setvalue

Comment: I's a common error but I never saw it w/o calling `reset()` or `setValue()`. You could set a breakpoint to see what triggers the update.

Comment: Its very strange as there are few value changes methods on the form which I have commented to avoid triggering any updates. The moment I add a new control , it flags with this error. So the error is not just limited to alternate. This were also happens when I add a form control  to the parent form group

Comment: If possible, can you replicate this on stackbliz?

Answer (score 0):

what about your  component?

You can try use a getter

```
get alternateGroup(){
  return this.formGroup .get('alternate') as FormGroup
}
```

And use

```
   <div class="field" [formGroup]="alternateGroup">
   <!--instead of
   <div class="field" formGroupName="alternate">
   -->
       ...
   </div>
```

But I'm not pretty sure that solve the problem

Comment: I tried your suggestion but exactly the same error

Comment: @Tom, I don't know about your `app-yes-no-multilingual`. In general I prefer pass as input of one component the own formContol instead the "formControlName". I imagine the problem is that your component can not get the "FormGroup", but it's impossible know if you don't put the code -or the revelant part of the code of this component- Imagine you use a `@Host() form:FormGroupDirective` in the constructor or some similar.