# Reactive Form, with FormArray of child components returning error

Tags: angular

I am figuring out how to refactor a complex form into smaller forms.

Essentially there is a parent form that will have a an array of child components which contain their owner forms.

Parent TS

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    mainAddress: [null, Validators.required],
    addresses: this.fb.array([]),
  });
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  get addresses() {
    return this.form.controls['addresses'] as FormArray;
  }
  removeAddress(i: number) {
    this.addresses.removeAt(i);
  }

  addAddress() {
    this.addresses.push(
      this.fb.control({
        address: [null, Validators.required],
      })
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <app-address-form formControlName="mainAddress"></app-address-form>
  <hr />
  <ng-container formArrayName="addresses">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let addressForm of addresses.controls; index as i">
      <app-address-form [formControlName]="i"></app-address-form>
      <button (click)="removeAddress(i)">Remove Address</button>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
</form>
<button (click)="addAddress()">Add Address</button>
```

Child Address TS

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-address-form',
  templateUrl: './address-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./address-form.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: AddressFormComponent,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: AddressFormComponent,
    },
  ],
})
export class AddressFormComponent
  implements ControlValueAccessor, OnDestroy, Validator
{
  @Input()
  legend: string;

  form: FormGroup = this.fb.group({
    addressLine1: [null, [Validators.required]],
    addressLine2: [null, [Validators.required]],
    zipCode: [null, [Validators.required]],
    city: [null, [Validators.required]],
  });

  onTouched: Function = () => {};

  onChangeSubs: Subscription[] = [];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnDestroy() {
    for (let sub of this.onChangeSubs) {
      sub.unsubscribe();
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(onChange: any) {
    const sub = this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(onChange);
    this.onChangeSubs.push(sub);
  }

  registerOnTouched(onTouched: Function) {
    this.onTouched = onTouched;
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    if (disabled) {
      this.form.disable();
    } else {
      this.form.enable();
    }
  }

  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value) {
      console.log(value);
      this.form.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
    }
  }

  validate(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      return null;
    }

    let errors: any = {};

    errors = this.addControlErrors(errors, 'addressLine1');
    errors = this.addControlErrors(errors, 'addressLine2');
    errors = this.addControlErrors(errors, 'zipCode');
    errors = this.addControlErrors(errors, 'city');

    return errors;
  }

  addControlErrors(allErrors: any, controlName: string) {
    const errors = { ...allErrors };

    const controlErrors = this.form.controls[controlName].errors;

    if (controlErrors) {
      errors[controlName] = controlErrors;
    }

    return errors;
  }
}
```

Child Address HTML

```html
<fieldset [formGroup]="form">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Address Line 1"
      formControlName="addressLine1"
      (blur)="onTouched()"
    />
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Address Line 2"
      formControlName="addressLine2"
      (blur)="onTouched()"
    />
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="Zip Code"
      formControlName="zipCode"
      (blur)="onTouched()"
    />
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="City"
      formControlName="city"
      (blur)="onTouched()"
    />
  </mat-form-field>
</fieldset>
```

```
Error i get is : 

    Error: NG01002: Must supply a value for form control with name: 'addressLine1'
```

Please keep in mind i am trying to avoid duplication of code by separating out as much as i can (DRY principle).

Appreciate any feedback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You has an array of **FormControls** (*) (each FormControl "store" a complex object with properties: addressLine1,addressLine2,zipCode and city, but the FormArray is still a FormArray of FormControls)

So, your function addAddress should be like

```
  addAddress() {
    this.addresses.push(this.fb.control(null))
  }
```

(*)Exists two approach when we work with nested forms. One is your approach: create a custom formControl that store a complex object and the "sub-formGroup" is created inside the component. The another is create the "sub-formGroup" in main component and pass the formGroup to a component (in this last case you not create a custom form control that implements ControlValueAccessor else a simple component with an `@Input`

**Update** about function validate in person.component and adress.component

In person.component you can crete a function validate like

```
control:AbstractControl //<--if you want to see the error
                        //in .html you can use
                        //{{control.errors|json}}

validate(control: AbstractControl) {

    if (!this.control) this.control = control; //<--this line is only if
                                               //we can "get" the control

    if (this.form.valid)
      return null;

    //if only give a generic error
    //return {error:'form not fullfilled'}

    let errors: any = null;
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach((e: any) => {

      //see that this.adresses is a FormArray, the formArray has no errors
      //else his elements

      if (e == 'addresses') {
        this.addresses.controls.forEach((x,i) => {
          const err = x.errors;
          if (err) {
            errors = errors || {};
            errors[e+'.'+i] = err;
          }
        });
      } else {
        const err = this.form.get(e).errors;

        if (err) {
          errors = errors || {};
          errors[e] = err;
        }
      }
    });
    return errors;
  }
}
```

and when you add the adress use updateValueAndValidity

```
  addAddress() {
    this.addresses.push(this.fb.control(null));
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
    this.form.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
```

The function validate to the adress.form like

```
  validate(control: AbstractControl) {
    if (!this.control) this.control = control;
    if (this.form.valid) return null;

    //if only give a generic error
    //return {error:'form not fullfilled'}

    let errors: any = null;
    Object.keys(this.form.controls).forEach((e: any) => {
      const err = this.form.get(e).errors;
      if (err) {
        errors = errors || {};
        errors[e] = err;
      }
    });

    return errors;
  }
```

Your [forked stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-h8tulz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fperson-form%2Fperson-form.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Faddress-form%2Faddress-form.component.ts)

Comment: I tried that, gives me ontrol.registerOnChange is not a function error which is nastier

Comment: @Aeseir, I made a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-okpnpg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html). Check if you're importing all the necesary modules in your app.module:`ReactiveFormsModule`, `MatFormFieldModule` and `MatInputModule`

Comment: this is really weird. On my localhost it doesn't work, yet i have tried this in stackblitz with your and mine (did one from scratch) and it works perfectly.
Now the validation doesn't roll up, i.e. if i add adress as child of address, it doesn't get the validation of the child address (example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-djfxnz)

Comment: @Aeseir, I update my answer to show a way to create the "validate function in yours component. I hope can help you

Comment: thank you, i created another similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72433749/parent-form-returning-incorrect-validation-from-nested-form. It bugs me to no avail that validation doesn't propagate.

Answer (score 0):

This has a similar solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047540/angular-reactive-form-error-must-supply-a-value-for-form-control-with-name).

If you're using the `setValue()` method on a `FormGroup` you will need to update all of the controls within that group. If you're only updating a single control, you need to use `patchValue()` instead. Otherwise you will get the NG01002 error.

Change this:

```
  writeValue(value: any) {
    if (value) {
      console.log(value);
      this.form.setValue(value, { emitEvent: false });
    }
  }
```

To this, adding the control you want to update as parameter:

```
  writeValue(controlToUpdate, value: any) {
    if (value) {
      console.log(value);
      this.form.patchValue({controlToUpdate: value},{emitEvent: false});
    }
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That is a very different issue. Problem is not with setValue, as the value is passed from parent to child through writeValue, in this scenario that only happens on init. Changes to form data then occur at child level.