# How to set the values of mat-select

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular14, mat-select

I try to load to the form the values of the object when I click the form opens i got an undefined data error.

I got to conclusion that my error is because I don't give the value right to the mat-select.

in the ngOnInit() of the diaog i call the api for the data i want to put in the mat-select.

this is the func:

```
getAuthors() {
this._authorService.getAuthors().subscribe(result => {
  this.authrosDb = result;
  console.log(this.authrosDb.data);
});
```

}

when i do the console log i do get the values but the error saying that the data is undefined,so i got to the conclusion that this is might happening because the select loads before the data is passed.
when i open the add form i can add all and see the values in the select. [This is the add form with the values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5vbv.png)

but when i want to update all the inputs beside the select
has the values of the row

[this is the udate from all have values only the selct isnt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vsrdc.png)

this is the select  author section in my form:

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Author</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="authorId" placeholder="Author">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let author of authrosDb.data" value={{author.authorId}}> 
      {{author.authorName}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field
```

and this is how I give the values to my inputs :

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.getAuthors();
  this.getGenres();
  if (this.data.id != '' && this.data.id != null) {
    this._bookService.getBook(this.data.id).subscribe(response => {
      this.editBook = response;
      console.log(this.editBook);
      this.bookForm.setValue({
        bookId: this.editBook.data.bookId,
        bookName: this.editBook.data.bookName,
        authorId: this.editBook.data.authorId,
        bookPublishedYear: this.editBook.data.bookPublishedYear,
        genreId: this.editBook.data.genreId,
        bookLanguage: this.editBook.data.bookLanguage,
        bookNumOfPages: this.editBook.data.bookNumOfPages,
        bookCopys: this.editBook.data.bookCopys
      });
    });
  }
}
```

this is bookForm:

```
bookForm = this.builder.group({
    bookId: this.builder.control({ value: '', disabled: true }),
    bookName: this.builder.control('', Validators.required),
    authorId: this.builder.control('', Validators.required),
    bookPublishedYear: this.builder.control('', Validators.required),
    genreId: this.builder.control('', Validators.required),
    bookLanguage: this.builder.control('', Validators.required),
    bookNumOfPages: this.builder.control('', Validators.required),
    bookCopys: this.builder.control('', Validators.required)
  });
```

[Html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecXW2.png)

tho its adding and updating the right values.
I'm new to angular so it's be helpful if anyone could explain my mistake and show me how to fix it, thx in advance!.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular reactive Form error: Must supply a value for form control with name:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51047540/angular-reactive-form-error-must-supply-a-value-for-form-control-with-name)

Comment: thx for the answer,unfortunately  i dont understand the solution because im new to angular i dont get what i did wrong. i have other form with mat-select which works but the diffrence i just type a string as options and here it an obj book.

Comment: Could you show us more of the code for `this.bookForm`? How did you declare and initialize it?

Comment: sure, i just added it.

Comment: Is `this.editBook.data.authorId` undefined? Maybe the key from the server has a different name?

Comment: you were right,now i dont get this error but whn i open the form the select dont. in tis case i have a tbl tow of book and i want to open the for and see the author of the book chosen.

Answer (score 1):

Use "safe operator" in .html to avoid initial error (at first `authrosDb` imagine is null)

```
<!--see the "?" between authrosDb and .data-->
<mat-option *ngFor="let author of authrosDb?.data" value={{author.authorId}}>
```

or declare in .ts your variable authrosDb with data

```
authrosDb:any={data:[],...rest of properties}
```

BTW. two things

1. Use `[value]="author.authorID"` instead of
   `value={{author.authorID}}`. If author.authorID is a number the
   interpolation (the ``` {{``}} ``` convert the value to a string else the
   binding (the `[` `]`) not do it
2. I suggest you change the name `authrosDb` by `authorsDb`, for me is
   confusing (and I imagine for you when you see the code after some
   days)

Answer (score 0):

Did you assign a `formGroup` attribute to the `<form>` tag in your template? It should look like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="bookForm"></form>
```

Only then you are able to set the `formControlName` attributes for the group's controls.

Comment: yes i did                                                                                                                                <form class="example-form" [formGroup]="bookForm" (ngSubmit)="saveBook()">